# How to specify the legend box size in ggplot/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R/ggplot2, I have multiple plots, each of which has a legend box.
I want the legend box to be the same width for each plot, but ggplot2 tries to dynamically size the legend box based on the legend name, key values, etc. (which are unique to each plot).
The various plots must fit into a specified publication slot, with a specified width for the legend, and the plots must be made separately (so faceting to guarantee identical legend widths across the plots isn't possible).
Looking at `theme` I couldn't find an option to specify the legend box width ... any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the `keywidth` argument: `guides(color = guide_legend(keywidth = 10))` -- for example: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, col = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(keywidth = 10)
  )`

Comment: That increases the width of each key/value. What I'd like is within each legend the default size (e.g. size = 1) for each key, but for the background 'box' to be a fixed width, even if that means a large margin around each key/value within the legend.

Comment: And using a fixed a margin does not help? Such as: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, col = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    legend.margin = margin(5, 50, 5, 50)
  )`

Comment: Nope, that just controls the margin only, such that the total size is the bounding-box around the content plus the margins, and the contents' bounding-box itself is still dynamically sized.

Comment: You can consider `plot_grid()` from the `cowplot` package (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/shared_legends.html)): extract out the legend from each plot, plot the legend-less plot & legend separately with a specified `rel_widths` determining the space allocated to each.

Comment: just curious, did you find any solution @mmuurr

Comment: @AlienDeg not really :-/ ... just create the plot without the legend then hop over to Illustrator (or other equivalent vector-based design program) and hand-create the legend (e.g. using color-picker tooling). Meh.

Comment: Cheers, i removed legend title with + theme(legend.title = element_blank())

Answer (score 26):

To specify the legend box size you could use `+ theme(legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm"))`.

```
library(tidyverse)
tb <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 10:1, c = rep(1:2, 5))

ggplot(tb, aes(a, b, colour = c)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.2, "cm"))
```

More details and additional modifications are [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes) and under the **keywidth** argument [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html).

Answer (score 3):

@Z.lin had the right approach in the comments.  Based on https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/shared_legends.html this might look something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
```

Make a ggplot object

```
my_plot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, colour = Species))+
    geom_point()
```

Extract the legend

```
my_legend <- get_legend(
  # create some space to the left of the legend
  my_plot + theme(legend.box.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 12))
)
```

Re-plot your plot in a grid without the legend (can combine multiple plots here if desired)

```
my_plot_nl <-  <- plot_grid(
  my_plot + theme(legend.position="none"),
  align = 'vh',
  hjust = -1,
  nrow = 1
)
```

Recombine your legend-free plot and legend and specify the relative width of each.  The plot now takes up 3/4 of the plot width and the legend 1/4.

```
plot_grid(my_plot_nl, my_legend, rel_widths = c(3,1))
```

If you do this for each plot, making sure to use the same `rel_widths` and saving the figures using the same dimensions, the plot area and legend should be consistent across them.

Comment: I've used the cowplot method successfully for this kind of graph manipulation. However, I think moving your `align = 'vh',  hjust = -1,  nrow = 1`arguments out of `my_plot_nl` and into the arguments of the final `plot_grid()` call prevents some unnecessary errors. Save all the grid specifications for when you are actually combining the graph and legend.

Answer (score -2):

You might attempt to change your `theme` call as follows:

```r
theme(legend.margin =margin(r=10,l=5,t=5,b=5))?
```